# How does this recursive function resolve and why does it output what it does

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I found myself unable to understand this example of a recursive function:

```
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  console.log('begin:' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end:' + i);
}
foo(3);
```

The output is:

```
begin:3
begin:2
begin:1
begin:0
end:0
end:1
end:2
end:3
```

I understand how normal and nested functions work, and I think the `return;` here is supposed to exit the function when `i` gets lower than `0`, so when `i = -1`, the first `console.log()` didn't show, but why after `foo(-1 - 1)` we get the output `end:0` ?

Comment: it's i-1 not -1-1 and in i=-1 nothing is outputted

Comment: On your code if you do `foo(-1-1)` or `foo(-2)` you'll get `undefined`.

Comment: When `i = -1`, the function returns immediately and nothing is shown at all. It never will call `foo(-1 - 1)`, instead it returns to where it was called - which is the line `foo(i - 1)` in the call where `i` was `0`.

Comment: The stack is built up and when the base case is reached it is unwound, which is the opposite process.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, this is so confusing, I still can't understand how i became 0 -> 1 -> 2 then 3.

Comment: @dwix `i` doesn't really change at all. For every invocation of the function, there's a new variable `i` (but with a different value). So when it returns from the call, the local `i` still has the same value as before the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand you must visualize the stack. Let me take you through the execution process:

1. We start by calling `foo(3)`, so `i` is 3. Since `i` is not less than 0, log `begin:3`. Call `foo(2)`
2. `i` is now 2. Since `i` is not less than 0, log `begin:2`. Call `foo(1)`
3. `i` is now 1. Since `i` is not less than 0, log `begin:1`. Call `foo(0)`
4. `i` is now 0. Since `i` is not less than 0, log `begin:0`. Call `foo(-1)`
5. `i` is now -1. Since `i` *is* less than 0, we return and go up the stack. Continue from where we left off, the second log in `foo(0)`:

   ```
   console.log('end:' + i);
   ```

   `end:0` is logged because `i` is equal to 0. `foo(0)` has resolved, go up the stack to `foo(1)`
6. Continue from the second log in `foo(1)`. `end:1` is logged because `i` is equal to 1. `foo(1)` has resolved, go up the stack to `foo(2)`
7. Continue from the second log in `foo(2)`. `end:2` is logged because `i` is equal to 2. `foo(2)` has resolved, go up the stack to `foo(3)`.
8. Continue from the second log in `foo(3)`. `end:3` is logged because `i` is equal to 3. `foo(3)` has resolved and thus the call is completely resolved.

This will yield:

```
begin:3 //Step 1
begin:2 //Step 2
begin:1 //Step 3
begin:0 //Step 4
end:0   //Step 5
end:1   //Step 6
end:2   //Step 7
end:3   //Step 8
```

Now, to answer the question:

> but why after foo(-1 - 1) we get the output end:0 ?

We never call `foo(-1 - 1)` because `foo(-1)` returns immediately - it's the base case. The reason it starts logging `end:i` where `i` is ascending is because execution continues where it left off before you recursed and called `foo(i - 1)`. Consequently, it logs `end:i` and then calls are resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I know I should understand what you said but I'm confused, I'm lost at step 5, I don't know how `i` is going to be 0, 1, 2 then 3. `i` is only going down from 3 to 0 ( because foo(i-1) is called ) and when `i` it reached -1 we exit. so the 1st log should log begin:3,2,1,0 and the second should output the same.

Comment: @dwix When a function is called, it is put on the call stack. When it is resolved (that is finished), it goes off the stack, by Last-In-First-Out (LIFO). So when we get to step 4, we call `foo(-1)`. That immediately resolves because -1 is less than 0 and thus we return. Once we return, the method call is popped off the stack, and we go back to the caller.

Comment: The caller, in this case was `foo(0)`. When we call a function, we execute the function then go back to where we left off in the caller. Since we left off right before the second log, we continue from there. `i` is a local variable in the function. The `i` in each function call is completely separate. When we go up the stack `i` stays the same as it has been in that certain call.

Comment: Since `i` was 0 in `foo(0)`, it logs `end:0`. It may be hard to understand at first, so if you have any other questions feel free to ask

Comment: I know I should understand this by now, I'll just stare at your explanation for the next 2 hours till I figure out what's happening. Thank you for your time. I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @dwix If you need any help, please feel free to ask, cheers :)

Comment: @dwix I hope [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hLbeu6hc/1/) can semi-clear it up for you. It demonstrates what I'm talking about, and illustrates the call stack. It can be applied here, as when the recursive call resolves, the call goes off the stack and then we start where we left off in the next call in the stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help, I'll do my best to understand and practice some examples, and I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the function do stop when i=0 but since foo(i-1) is called before console.log('end:' + i); the output of all the console.log('begin:' + i); are displayed before the end are displayed with the i value.

Indeed, what really happens here is:

- foo(3)

  - i=3 --> display : "begin 3";
  - Call foo(2)

    - i=2 --> display : "begin 2";
    - Call foo(1)

      - i = 1 --> display : "begin 1";
      - Call foo(0)

        - i = 0 --> display : "begin 0";
        - Call foo(-1) --> return
        - Go back to foo(0), display "end 0"
        - End of foo(0)
      - Go back to foo(1), display "end 1"
      - End of foo(1) ...

And so on.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean in the step `Go back to foo(0), display "end 0"` how and where it is going backward ?

Comment: It's not going backward, the function foo(-1) is inside the function foo(0), and after the call of foo(-1) there is "console.log('end ' + i)".

Answer (score 0):

this really helped me out. hope it helps someone out..

```
    function foo(i) {
    console.log(i, 'called');
  if (i < 0) {
       return `${i} is returning`;
    } else {
       console.log('continue');
    }
console.log('begin:' + i);
const value = foo(i - 1);
console.log(value);
console.log(i, 'returned');
console.log('end:' + i);
}
foo(3);
```

every step along the way gets put in a queue [3,2,1,0] so when the program returns or exits with -1 and is able to run end it starts going back up the queue and letting the queue close or end. I tried my best to explain... My big Bro helped me out.. :)